Medha Dakhinamurthy Chakra
Namaste,
I was looking for a Medha Dakshinamurthy Chakra to supplement my Medha Dakshinamurthy Mantra Sadhana. I have a version of the chakra in Kannada but the print is not clear. It would be very humble and great if anyone can share the picture of the Chakra with me.

This is the Chakra that I have from the book authored by Shri. Gunjuru Prakasha Shastri, but the image of Chakra is not clear enough.
Thanks in advance.
